# Is it possible to build a lock screen application on iOS?

Tags: ios

My goal is to build a lockscreen application on iOS platform. For example, whenever a user tries to unlock the phone my app will be running.

The main purpose is let's say user wants to play a social media like Twitter, Facebook. User has to go through my application first before playing those social medias.

It is something like web blocker or something. I know that iOS is very strict but just wondering if it is possible or not.

Comment: No, it is not possible.  You cannot alter the user's experience that way.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of permissions are not allowed , securing the user privacy.
Please go through the list which shows what permissions we can get from user.
Apart from this , user cannot have alternative control over iPhone application.

> iOS helps prevent apps from accessing a user’s personal information
>   without permission. Additionally, in Settings, users can see which
>   apps they have permitted to access certain information, as well as
>   grant or revoke any future access. This includes access to:

```
Contacts
Calendars
Reminders
Photos
Motion activity and fitness
Location Services
Apple Music
Your music and video activity
Social media accounts, such as Twitter and Facebook
Microphone
Camera
HomeKit
Health
Speech recognition
Bluetooth sharing
Your media library
```

> If the user signs in to iCloud, apps are granted access by default to
>   iCloud Drive. Users may control each app’s access under iCloud in
>   Settings. Additionally, iOS provides restrictions that prevent data
>   movement between apps and accounts installed by an MDM solution and
>   those installed by the user.